# Changing the position of the grid walls in an mplot3d figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

When making a figure using the `mplot3d` package, three gray walls are automatically created and the axis ticks and grid lines are placed along these walls, as shown in [this mplot3d example which I will be referring to later](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.html).

These walls are positioned such that they are placed slightly outside the given axis limits. For instance, as you can see in the figure of the referred example, the vertical grid walls stretch from slightly below 0 to slightly above 1. A negative side effect of this is that the bottom wall (the floor of the plot, if you will), is placed at a *z* coordinate slightly below 0. This makes it difficult to accurately read the grid. For instance, the red surface in the example figure hovers over the bottom wall, and therefore looks like it's positioned along *y* = 1.1 instead of its correct position of *y* = 1.

I've tried to find out how to change the position of these grid walls without success. Their colour can be changed using the axis3d method `set_pane_color(color)` and there's another axis3d method `set_pane_pos(xys)` which is undocumented and does nothing as far as I can tell. Is it in any way possible to position the grid walls manually?

Comment: I'm sorry that I couldn't link an image along with the post to make it easier to comprehend, but I don't have sufficient reputation to do so.

Comment: Can you host your picture externally and provide a link to that (e.g. tinypic.com)? Someone with more reputation could edit it into your question.

Comment: The image I would have shown is the one [in the example I refer to in the question](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/polys3d_demo.html), so it's already available. Just not as immediately visible as I would have liked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [2D plots are not sitting flush against 3D-axis walls in python mplot3D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196503/2d-plots-are-not-sitting-flush-against-3d-axis-walls-in-python-mplot3d)

Comment: @decvalts It is indeed a duplicate, and I've now flagged my question as such. Thanks!